# ActiveModel: Mimic a column type datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, callback, type-conversion, activemodel

I am using an ActiveModel model `DateRange` with attributes `:from` and `:to` and I want it to behave as follows..

```
  d = DateRange.new
=> #<DateRange:0x0000010532d3f8>
  d.from = "03/03/2010"
=> Wed, 03 Mar 2010
  d.to  = Date.today
=> Mon, 3 Mar 2014
```

In other words, whenever an attribute is set, if it is in string format it should be parsed into a date format.
Is there an ActiveModel callback function which will run immediately when an attribute is changed? If not, what would be best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any callbacks, what you need are custom setter methods:

```
class DateRange
  attr_reader :from, :to

  def from=(value)
    # implementation
  end

  def to=(value)
    # implementation
  end
end
```